# Windows 8 Metro App Side Load Deployment

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, directx, windows-store, sideloading

I am currently developing a Windows Store App that will eventually be targeted at the ARM devices when they are available. For now, I have been developing and testing from Visual Studio on my desktop computer and everything works fine. However, when I try to create an app package that I can pass along to others within my company for testing purposes, the application will not run properly.

The solution includes two projects. The first is a C++ project that is set to build a dll file. The purpose for this is to expose the Direct2D and DirectWrite libraries that seem to be unaccessible to a C# project. The second project is the C# project that references this dll for drawing functions and includes a XAML interface and most of the program logic. All of this works flawlessly on my development machine from within Visual Studio (and also when installing the package).

When I send the package files to other individuals within the company, the installation appears to work fine by installing with the PowerShell script. The tile appears in the start screen and the program will launch for a few seconds. The C# and XAML interface appears, but the DirectX portion of the application is not visible and the entire application shuts down within a few seconds. This makes me believe that the dll may not be installing or referenced correctly upon installation. I have checked the package file, and the dll file is included in the package after the build process is complete.

I have packaged a few different test programs (MSDN Samples) that have all installed on their machines, but we get the same results that they will not run (again, all samples run fine on my development machine when building them). The only test project that worked properly was a simple C# project that did not use DirectX at all. Any of the DirectX samples that I tried have all failed (including the native C++ samples that do not use C# at all).

To be clear, the process I use for building is going to Project -> Store -> Create App Packages and choosing the No option for uploading to the Windows Store.

Does anyone have any ideas on what might be going wrong with the build or installation process?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Just a side-question, but: can you launch the project on the test machine from Visual Studio? As in - can you get the application running without deploying it as a separate package?

Comment: Yes, any of their machines that already have Visual Studio can launch the project within Visual Studio. And further, once they launch from within Visual Studio, the Powershell Deployment method works fine. There seems to be something that launching within Visual Studio does that makes everything work. However, this is not a viable option for all of the people that I need to pass the application on to.

Answer (score 2):

Does it work with the [Metro Sideloader](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/CompuSight-Metro-App-b31b65da)?  I am not sure if it just adds a UI to the Powershell script, but it works for my team and me for testing...

Good luck!

Comment: I just tried the Metro Sideloader as you suggested and it doesn't seem to work. I downloaded the exe, ran as administrator and followed the instructions on the page. Everything appeared to install properly and the application reported a success. However, the application never showed up on the tile screen, and was not found in the All Applications section either. At this point, I think I will just wait a few more days until the RT tablets come out and attempt to get an internal build for those. That is really what I am going to be targeting anyway. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Are you side loading a Debug version of your DirectX app onto a machine that does not have the Windows SDK installed?  Visual Studio's default DirectX projects and the samples on MSDN both request the D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG flag when creating the D3D Device.  Device creation will fail if the Windows SDK is not installed on the machine running the code.

Here are a few different options that will allow you to unblock yourself. Any one of these should give you the desired result:

- Create a Release package and deploy that instead of a Debug package.
- or - Go to DirectXBase.cpp and remove the D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG flag from the code.
- or - Install the Remote Debugging tools for Visual Studio on the target machines.  This will install the necessary SDK components to allow creation of D3D Debug devices.  The other cool thing about this option is that once you're set up you won't have to create packages manually and side load them anymore.  Just tell Visual Studio the name of your ARM machine and press F5 to deploy it remotely.  More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How are you deploying the native DLL with your project?  Are you using project-to-project references?  Can you verify that your DLL is ending up in the final package, in the root of the package application directory?

I recommend using [Sysinternals Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to watch your application load on the target machine.  If it crashes or fails, you can look in the log history for which DLL it is trying to load and failing.  Typically this will show up as a repeated series of DLL load probes (it will try and load the dll from the application directory, and then proceed to try a number of other paths).